# how to Add Input Text Field to Pdf (AcroForm) with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

it's should be simple but i couldn't find the answer anywhere in google or the source documentation.

[someone have asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222759/add-acroform-with-pdfsharp) 4 years ago, but still no one answered!

if it's not possible. can someone please confirm, so that i can find another pdf generator library that can do that. because it's very important in my case to be able to generate pdf with input capability

thanks!

Comment: Methinks it should work, but I cannot provide sample code (now).

Comment: please do when you have the time, i'm running out of option for opensource pdf generator library for c#. so i really hopes pdfSharp can do this

Comment: I would refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222759/add-acroform-with-pdfsharp) question as it is similar to yours.

Answer (score -1):

See [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74853766/9758687) with Links on how to to add text to an existing field and also how to add a field to a PDF document using PDFsharp.

Answer (score -6):

## We will go through the step by step

1. First you need to create object of PdfReader

   - `PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(templatePath);`
     here "templatePath" is the template(sample file) where you write your all data
2. Then create source file where all data is rendered(write)

   - `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(DocPath));`
     "DocPath" is the path where output file is save
3. Then Initialize PdfStamper  and AcroFields  object :

   ```
   PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(newFile), FileMode.Create));
   AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
   ```
4. Then set Field in PDF :

   ```
       pdfFormFields.SetField("this text should field name in PDF(template PDF)", "Actual value you want to write");
   ```
5. Dispose all objects

   ```
       pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
       pdfStamper.Close();
       pdfReader.Close();
   ```

Comment: Good that the code is working, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: are you sure its for pdfSharp?
because i cant find pdfStamper in the library

Comment: The answer is not for PDFsharp, that's why it does not answer the question.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow any knowledge of whether it is possible to be done?